# Gzip support - Do a need a non gzipped copy of the files?

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, gzip

So I decided to manually gzip all my files on the serrver. Now I wonder if it's safe to only have gziped files? Or will I for some reason need to have a "non gzipped copy" of the files?

I am thinking about: Browser support, Robots, Google Analytics, anything else you can think of...

**Will it be safe to only use:**

- index.html.gz
- style.css.gz
- javascript.js.gz

**For example:**

```
<a herf="www.domain.com/folder/">link to folder with index.html.gz in it</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sub.domain.com/javascript.js.gz"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://sub.domain.com/style.css.gz" />
```

**If I put this in my .htaccess file:**

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
DirectoryIndex index.html.gz
```

Comment: Why not just use mod_deflate, and let it deal with the compression ?

Comment: I believe static files are a little bit faster. Also I save some "server capacity" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible that some client comes along that doesn't support gzip encoded content.

I don't think any current desktop web browser has that drawback, but other pieces of software could have this: search engine bots (not the major ones, probably), mobile phone browsers, screen reader software, ...

By not providing non-gzip variations of all your files you restrict the target audience of your site.

Comment: I see what you are saying. There is a risk. It would be greate if i could get a real case where this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

**The following code works in:**

- FF (tested on PC)
- IE (tested on PC)
- C (tested on PC)
- SF (tested on PC)
- Iphone
- HTC

**Htaccess file:**

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
DirectoryIndex index.gz.html
```

Note that I have changed the order (gz.html instead of .html.gz)

**HTML for css and javascript files:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://qwer.se/compresscss/style.gz.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://qwer.se/compresscss/java.gz.js"></script>
```

Note that I have changed the order gz in css and java.

The reason for .gz.html, .gz.css, .gz.js  is Safari. I can't find any information about this but it works. I am not an expert, so don't take my word for that it is correct.

What do you all think of this solution?